# Free implementation of multi-layer perceptron?

Tags: open-source, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, perceptron

Is there a free (preferably public-domain or BSD-like license, but GPL will do) implementation of a multi-layer perceptron anywhere on the net?

I have textbook examples but the licenses are too restrictive, and although I can just about follow the math in the Wikipedia articles I'm not confident enough of getting it right and it's hard to test.

I've done a quick google search and found some free (as in beer) binary-only versions.  I'm hoping to find an MLP which is part of a larger open-source project.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[FANN (Fast Artifical Neural Network Library)](http://leenissen.dk/fann/) is a great general-purpose neural-network library written in C but has bindings for just about any language you might want (C++, .NET, Python, Mathematica among others). Even better, it's open-source and licensed under the LGPL, so I'd imagine that would be fine for you.

[Neuron.NET](http://sourceforge.net/projects/neurondotnet/) is another good alternative if you're using .NET (also open-source), though it's licensed under the GPL.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I studied the source of Neuron.NET in order to understand the math.  It's actually a lot simpler than I expected and I was able to implement a faster version in Java.

Comment: C/C++ Perceptron: http://sourceforge.net/projects/ccperceptron/

Answer (score 1):

[WEKA](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/) includes a multi-layer perceptron implementation.  I haven't examined the source code myself but its GPL I believe.

Answer (score 1):

[OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/) has a Feedforward neural network implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at http://neuralensemble.org/trac/PyNN! It is a unified layer to a lot of different free simulators such as BRIAN, NEST, NEURON, etc.